# What is the purpose of specifying from attribute in smtp element?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

When sending mail using system.net. Having specified **from attribute** in system.net->mailsetting->smtp. In send method we have to pass from address once again, so what is the purpose of specifying it in the config?

```
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" **from="xyz@xyz.com"**>
      <network host="smtpout.secureserver.net" port="80" userName="xyz@xyz.com" password="xyz-password" />
  </smtp>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the from address never changes, this is a good place to set it.

Many applications send email from a single account, so configuring it there instead of *hard coding* it makes sense.

This value is used in the [parameterless constructor of `MailMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144707.aspx).